# A Reader monad for multiple arguments?

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

Is there an equivalent to the `Reader` monad that's equivalent to `a -> b -> c` rather than just `a -> b`. I know I could do `(a, b) -> c` but I'm not sure that's going to be very ergonomic.

Comment: [shameless self-promotion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-stack)

Comment: Just in case someone reading this question is writing an app, in that circumstance I would replace `a` in the reader monad with a problem-specific custom type containing all the relevant things I want access to in the main body of my app. Probably a record type.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make that a monad is by wrapping it which may not be what you're after. The instance can be derived

```hs
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader

newtype Reader2 a b c = Reader2 (a -> b -> c)
 deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadFix, MonadReader a)
 via ReaderT a ((->) b)
```

If you derive `Representable` it witnesses the isomorphism between `Reader2 a b c` and `(a, b) -> c`

```hs
index    :: Reader2 a b c -> ((a, b) -> c)
tabulate :: ((a, b) -> c) -> Reader2 a b c
```

Comment: Why not `newtype ReaderT2 e f m a = ReaderT2 { unReaderT2 :: ReaderT e (ReaderT f m) a }`?

Comment: That works great, and then `type Reader2 a b = ReaderT2 a b Identity` but why do you keep the newtypes inside the definition? And there is a new package [*deriving-trans*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-trans) that lets you derive the lifting function for monad transformers: ``MonadTrans via ReaderT e `ComposeT` ReaderT f``

Comment: For `ReaderT`, it probably wouldn't make sense, but for more complicated things you may want to maintain abstraction.